# Prism 6: RequestNavigate() working for just one region

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, regions

I have three regions:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ContentControl  DockPanel.Dock="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:
         RegionNames.TheUpperRegion}" Margin="5" />
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:
         RegionNames.TheBottomRegion}" Margin="5"/>
    </DockPanel>

    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.TheWholeRegion}"
     Margin="5"  />
</Grid>
```

This code navigates from `TheWholeRegion` to `TheBottomRegion` region correctly:

```
Uri viewUpper = new Uri("ModuleItems", UriKind.Relative);
Uri viewBottom = new Uri("ModuleItems", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheBottomRegion, viewBottom);
var loginView = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Views.ElementAt(0);
regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Remove(loginView);
```

However, if I try to load two regions at once, then I see "System.Object" instead of Views:

```
Uri viewUpper = new Uri("ModuleItems", UriKind.Relative);
Uri viewBottom = new Uri("ModuleItems", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheUpperRegion, viewUpper);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheBottomRegion, viewBottom);
var loginView = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Views.ElementAt(0);
regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Remove(loginView);
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: If you enter another contract name than the ModuleItems ? I think you are trying to navigate to the same view in viewUpper and viewBotton, then the same view will be in both regions which is IMHO not possible, try with another sample view in viewBottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I need is to register a type mapping between `System.Object` and your view type in my `Unity` container:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
{            
   Container.RegisterType<object, TheBottomControl>("ModuleItemsBottom");
   Container.RegisterType<IBottomViewModel, TheBottomControlViewModel>();
   Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<TheBottomControl>();

   Container.RegisterType<object, TheUpperControl>("ModuleItemsUpper");
   Container.RegisterType<IUpperViewModel, TheUpperControlViewModel>();            
   Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<TheUpperControl>();          
}
```

and code to request:

```
Uri viewUpper = new Uri("ModuleItemsUpper", UriKind.Relative);
Uri viewBottom = new Uri("ModuleItemsBottom", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheUpperRegion, viewUpper);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheBottomRegion, viewBottom);
var loginView = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Views.ElementAt(0);
regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Remove(loginView);
```